# Qt Tabs for Files

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, nokia

Well, i'm working on an IDE System, which can open multiple files at same time. I'm somewhat noob with Tabs.
What i'm trying to do is a TabSystem, you click a file on the File Tree and it opens a new tab for it and show it's content. You can switch to other tag then switch to that one, drag tabs, etc.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try to use `QTabWidget` + `QTabBar` for  your purposes ? http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtabwidget.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display your project tree you could use QTreeWidget. For file content you could use QTextEdit(for starter). Use QTabWidget to show multiple QTextEdits in different tabs.

Comment: Well i got part of it. Except the assign a QTextEdit to an QTabWidget.
Well, no clue of how create hte project system. It haves #include's on the project file which adds the files to the project.

Comment: use addTab(new QTextEdit(), "Tab Name") to add QTextEdit as a new tab. About 'how to crete the project system' that's another topic. If you have problems with the concept of your IDE you should ask another question for it.